# Why is there a minus sign in "$0" on Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, bash, shell

I've been a GNU/Linux user for years, but I can't figure out how to get usable process info on Mac.

I realized that `$0` resolves to `-bash` in my login shell on Mac OS (Snow Leopard). <del>This may break certain shell scripts that work fine in a Linux environment</del>*.

Unfortunately, the manpage does not mention this fact

> If bash is invoked with  a
>                 file of commands, $0 is set to the name of that file.  If bash is started with the -c option, then $0 is set to the
>                 first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present.  Otherwise, it is set to the file name  used  to
>                 invoke bash, as given by argument zero.

Does the minus sign have a special meaning?
 Is there anything like `/proc` or a command line tool that could me help find the associated executable?

<sub>* Silly me. Of course, $0 will evaluate to the script name, as stated in the manual</sub>

Comment: That is a hyphen, not a minus sign.

Comment: Well, it's a [hyphen-minus](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minus sign is the way the system tells the shell that it's invoked as a login shell and it should source `~/.profile` (for Bourne-compatible shells). This is true on Linux, OSX and every other unix. A script would not be run in a login shell. For a script, `$0` is the name of the script file (with or without the full path).

**ADDED**: The man page does explain (almost all) the different cases:

- “If bash is invoked with a file of commands, $0 is set to the name of that file.” This covers scripts executed with `bash myscript`, as well as the indirect case where the script is executed directly and starts with `#!/bin/bash`.
- “If bash is started with the -c option, then $0 is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present.” With `-c`, `$0` is set to whatever the caller explicitly indicates.
- “Otherwise, it is set to the file name used to invoke bash, as given by argument zero.” A login shell falls into this case: the shell is invoked with no arguments other than argument zero, so `$0` is set to argument zero. It is `login`, `su`, or whatever program handled the login that chooses the arguments that it passed to the shell, and prepends a `-` to argument zero to tell the shell that it's a login shell.

Perhaps some explanation of argument zero is in order. When a program is executed, ultimately, an `execve` system call takes place. That system call takes three arguments:

1. a file name, which must designate an existing, executable file. The kernel loads this file and transfers execution to it.
2. an array of strings, called the arguments. Element zero in this array is *by convention* the same file name as above, or the just the file name without the full path if the location of the executable was determined by searching the `$PATH` environment variable. There are exceptions to this convention, such as login shells.
3. another array of strings, called the environment.

When you call a program from the shell by typing `myprogram foo bar`, the arguments to `execve` are:
    1. `/usr/bin/myprogram` (assuming this is where the shell found `myprogram`)
    2. `myprogram`, `foo`, `bar`
    3. for each exported shell variable, the variable name followed by an equal sign and the value.

There is no general way to find the name of the executable file that was passed to `execve` from the running program. Under Linux, it's usually available as `/proc/$$/exe` where `$$` is the process ID. Every unix makes it available to `ps` but the inner workings of `ps` differ widely. The executable may be deleted or renamed while the program is running; in this case `ps` might report obsolete information or no information.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. But it seems [correct indeed](http://serverfault.com/questions/85248/solaris-determine-if-login-shell-su-or-not). Also, from the command line, `$0` is the name of the shell. Never knew that either. :-)

Comment: I never realized this happens in Liunx too. But it sure does. Okay, so IIUC [the login process spawns a shell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch51_09.htm#AUTOID-60378) and assigns it an "arbitrary" name, contrary to what the manpage suggests. Is there no way to get the real information back? Even `/proc/$$/cmdline` contains a minus sign. How would `ps` do it?

Comment: It's `/proc/self/exe` for the requesting process, and `/proc/$$/exe` for any process with PID `$$`; so `readlink /proc/$$/exe` will return shell's executable and `readlink /proc/self/exe` will return `readlink`'s.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
>                 If  command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process
>                 is created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.   If
>                 the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to  command.   This  is  what
>                 login(1) does.  ...

Comment: Thanks, I never used that. (Of course, technically, `login` does not call a bash internal. I just looked at the source: it's [`execle()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execle) in `shell.c`)

Comment: @Pumbaa: I think the manpage describes behavior of `login` when calling a shell, not vice versa.

Comment: @grawity: That's correct. I posted that excerpt simply to show that this behavior (having a dash) is by design and recognized as something more broadly applicable and not something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on with the -bash , but if you run bash again in the shell the value of $0 appears to be fine.

It seem to be something special os x is doing, cause if you run /usr/bin/login, which is the default script used by terminal program, the same problem with $0 appears.

Comment: True. Also, I just found that `top -pid $$` returns `bash`, while `ps $$` hooks up the minus sign. Very annoying.

Comment: (Why the line break rather than [a new paragraph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635)...?)